# Javascript map then filter unique array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-map

I know how to do both things separately, but I'm sure there must be a way to combine them.

I have an array of categories, which I am extracting from an array of objects:

```
 this.videoCategories = this.videos.map(v => v.category);
```

But of course there are duplicates in this array.  So now I do

```
this.uniqueVideoCategories = this.videoCategories.filter((item, index) => {
  return this.videoCategories.indexOf(item) === index;
});
```

Which works fine, I get an array of the categories without dupes.  But I'm trying to learn and dry up the code a bit by stringing them together, and this does not work - yields empty array

```
  constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {
    this.videos = videoService.getVideos();
    this.videoCategories = this.videos
      .map(v => v.category)
      .filter((item, index) => {
        return this.videoCategories.indexOf(item) === index;
      });
    console.log(this.videoCategories);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is empty because when you does filtering array `return this.videoCategories.indexOf(item) === index;`, field `this.videoCategories` was empty.

Try it:

```
this.videoCategories = this.videos
    .map(v => v.category)
    .filter((item, index, array) => {
        return array.indexOf(item) === index;
    });
```

Comment: item, index, array!  I always forget about passing the array.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `filter()` you are checking the index inside the array of objects. You can use the third argument of `filter()` method which will be the newly created array after `map()`

```
 constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {
    this.videos = videoService.getVideos();
    this.videoCategories = this.videos
      .map(v => v.category)
      .filter((item, index, arr) => {
        return arr.indexOf(item) === index;
      });
    console.log(this.videoCategories);
  }
```

Instead of using `filter()` and `indexOf()` you can use `Set` to remove duplicates. This will be the time-complexity `O(N)`

```
constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {
    this.videos = videoService.getVideos();
    this.videoCategories = [...new Set(this.videos.map(v => v.category))]
    console.log(this.videoCategories);
  }
```

Comment: Filter is faster https://blog.usejournal.com/performance-of-javascript-array-ops-2690aed47a50

Comment: I always forget about that third argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the solution is choosing the right data structure. ES6 has introduced [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which only contains unique objects.

Then you just do:

```
this.videoCategories = new Set(this.videos.map(v => v.category))
```

The uniqueness will be handled by browser implementation, instead of cluttering your codebase.

Comment: Filter is faster https://blog.usejournal.com/performance-of-javascript-array-ops-2690aed47a50

Comment: @WilliamLohan that example is spreading Set back to array...not a valid comparison. You may be correct but that's not a valid test for this use case

Comment: @WilliamLohan The article compares filter with expanding the set with `...`, I didn't suggest expanding it. At any rate, if performance mattered, I would suggest normal `for`. The intermediate `.map` is one extra allocation and loop through the array, much more important than `Set` vs `.filter` nuances.

Comment: Oh right I see, I just googled which is faster because filter-indexOf is my "goto" and saw Set solutions here and was curious

Answer (score 2):

```js
var videos = [
  { category: 'category1', title: 'Category 1'},
  { category: 'category1', title: 'Category 1'},
  { category: 'category1', title: 'Category 1'},
  { category: 'category2', title: 'Category 2'},
  { category: 'category2', title: 'Category 2'}
];
var categoryVideos =
  videos
    .map(v => v.category)
    .filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);
    
console.log(categoryVideos);
```

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

## Syntax

```
var newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

### Parameters

**callback**

Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise. It accepts three arguments:

- *element*: The current element being processed in the array.
- *index*: (Optional) The index of the current element being processed in the array.
- ***array*: (Optional) The array filter was called upon.**
- *thisArg*: (Optional) Value to use as this when executing callback.

### Return value

A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.videoCategories = this.videos
.map(v => v.category)
.filter((item, index, array) => 
    array.indexOf(item) === index;
);
```

If you don't use brackets and is just a line, you don't need the return.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {
  this.videos = videoService.getVideos();
  const categories = this.videos.map(v => v.category);
  this.videoCategories = [...new Set(categories)];
  console.log(this.videoCategories);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for your answer! Please note it is generally considered good practice to explain _why_ your code works. We are not a code-writing service after all, but a place to learn. Also refer to [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on this.